# Bootstrap and custom css, loading order misunderstandings

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have Bootstrap loaded and working all fine, via CDN, and I'm trying to override the bootstrap default size and color stylings for a `<caption>` tag. So, I've placed some css in my stylesheets/application.css file:

```
caption {
  font-size: 150%;
  color: #000000;
 }
```

My `application.html.rb` head looks like this:

```
<head>
  <title>Odot2</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Even though bootstrap is listed after the application.css manifest file the `font-size` css selector i defined in application.css does take effect, yet the `color` selector will only work if i move the bootstrap link before the application manifest link?

Why does one selector work and not the other and what is the correct way to be doing this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: And yes - you have to have application.css after bootstrap.css or you can use !important rule and don't care about order of CSS files, but it is not recommended.

Comment: Word of warning if you decide to use `!important` - if you ever had to add a new developer to the team and this new developer has a good understanding of css, using `!important` might cause a serious injury of your head.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bootstrap css defines caption as:

```
caption {
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  color: #777;
  text-align: left;
}
```

Note, there is no `font-size` there, but there is `color`.

In css, if the same property is defined in exactly same selector more then once, the second definition overrides the previous one. Hence if you define `color` first in your assets and you load `bootstrap` later on, bootstrap will override your definition. Since `font-size` is not used in bootstrap for this selector, order doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Ah, i see, of course! I understand now, thanks for the help. What is the correct method for my own custom stylesheet designed to override bootstrap styles, in terms of; naming, location and how i possibly split styles between various custom stylesheets pending their intended operations.

Answer (score 2):

Thats how CSS works - if two rules have the same specificity than the latter rule always wins:

*a.css*

```
p { color: blue; }
```

*b.css*

```
p { color: red; }
```

--

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="a.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="b.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>I'm red</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

That's why you always place libs at the top and your overrides under. That is unless you want to start a specificity war...

Answer (score 0):

The correct way, if you want to override a style defined in a library, is to put your own stylesheet after the stylesheet for the library, as you noticed.

Now the Bootstrap CSS does not define the caption color font size, so it doesn't matter where you put the size in your CSS; that's the size it will take. However, it does define the color, so in that case, the order in which the styles appear is important. The last one takes precedence.

Answer (score 0):

Use the custom style CSS at the last, after bootstrap CSS..it will over write the caption style. Hope it will resolve ur issue

Answer (score -1):

Just add important to your css attribute value to override default bootstrap CSS

caption {
  font-size: 150%;
  **color: #000000!important;**
 }

Hope that will be quick and work for you well.

thanks